# Youtube api v3 Comment - Insufficient Permission [403] c#

Tags: c#, .net, youtube, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to want to add comments to a video from my programm, but I get the following error:

```
Insufficient Permission [403]
```

Errors [
        Message[Insufficient Permission] Location[ - ] Reason[insufficientPermissions] Domain[global]
]

To log in I have this code:

```
        UserCredential credential;
        using (var stream = new FileStream(credentialsFile.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                // This OAuth 2.0 access scope allows for full read/write access to the
                // authenticated user's account.
                new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeForceSsl },
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None,
                new FileDataStore(this.GetType().ToString())
            );
        }

        var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = this.GetType().ToString()
        });
```

To insert the code I have this code:

```
CommentSnippet snippet = new CommentSnippet();
        snippet.TextOriginal = text;
        Comment comment = new Comment();
        comment.Snippet = snippet;
        CommentThreadSnippet threadSnippet = new CommentThreadSnippet();
        threadSnippet.VideoId = videoID;
        threadSnippet.TopLevelComment = comment;
        CommentThread commentThread = new CommentThread();
        commentThread.Snippet = threadSnippet;
        CommentThreadsResource.InsertRequest insertComment = youtubeService.CommentThreads.Insert(commentThread, "snippet");
        insertComment.Execute();
```

I read in other threads I should use the scope "YoutubeForceSsl", I also created a new OAuth credentials file, but it still doesn't work...

Thank you for all responses!

Paul